# Enforcing generics on a map

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a simple caching class. The cache is essentially a map from class to list.
I want to declare the map in a way to enforce that the list item class is the same as the class of the key. The following:

```
class Cache {
    private static Map<Class<? extends CodedEntity>, List<? extends CodedEntity>> map;
}
```

Is not enough because it won't enforce (in its decleration) what I want.
The map needs to be static and there is no point in declaring the class as T because I don't want it to be limited to a single type. Is there a syntactic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You map is private, why don't you enforce your need in accessor and mutator methods?

```
public <T extends CodedEntity> void addToCache(Class<T> key, List<T> values) {
    map.put(key, values);
}

public <T extends CodedEntit> List<T> getFromCache(Class<T> key) {
    return (List<T>) map.get(key);
}
```

Comment: Of course I can do this (and I did), it just seems weird to me that I can't find a way to define this in the field level. For example, I want that there won't be compiler warning in the return statement, for example.

Comment: Sorry -- that's not going to be doable.  Your API will be externally typesafe, but the Java type system isn't strong enough to prove things like "this cast here is safe."